# What is a bilinear system?

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, bilinear-form

I am studying control theory, and I am focusing on dynamical systems. While studying, I have met the topic of **bilinear systems** and of the **bilinear realization**.

What I cannot understand is the really beginning, so I **do not understand what a bilinear system is**.

In my notes I have that it is something expressed as:
$$
f(x,u)=f_1(x,u)+f_2(x,u)
$$

where it is said that $f_1$ is linear on the set $X\times U$ where $X$ is the set of state variables and $U$ is the set of inputs, and $f_2$ is bilinear on the set $X\times U$, and $h$ is linear on $X$, so I have a system of the type:
$$
\begin{cases}
f(x,u)=Ax+Bu+\sum_{i=1}^{p}N_ixu_i\\ 
h(x)=Cx
\end{cases}.
$$
(sorry for the bad indentation, I don't understand how to fix it)

Now, I honestly don't understand how to interpret this system. Infact, there is a summation and a matrix $N$ which I don't understand what it is, and moreover I don't have an intuition of what a bilinear system is.

About the bilinear realization, I mentioned it since I am studying bilinear systems in the context of dynamical system, and so in the next chapter i have to study it is present a description on how to pass from a state representation(explicit representaion) to a differential equation(implicit representation).

Can somebody please help me?